# JUnit test for a method by storing from database

Tags: java, junit4

I need to write a JUnit test case for the following method by taking and storing the values from database. Please find below code.

Service class name -> UserServiceImpl.java

```
@Override
    public AntaresUserDetials getUserDetails(String userId) {
        mapSubsidiariesToUser(this.subsidiaryService.listSubsidariesByUserId(null));
        UserDTO user = getUserDetailsById(userId);
        userDetials= new AntaresUserDetials();
        
        userDetials.setId(user.getUsrCf());
        userDetials.setFirstName("sss");
        userDetials.setLoginId(user.getRsqnamCf());
        userDetials.setUserType(user.getRsqsecprfCf());
        userDetials.getSecurityProfile().setName(user.getRsqsecprfCf());
        userDetials.getSecurityProfile().setSelected(true);
        userDetials.setLastName("sss");
        userDetials.setLastloginDate(user.getLstupdD());
        userDetials.setPassword(user.getRsqpwdCf());
        for(UserGroupDTO userGroupDto: userGroupService.listUserGroupByUserId(userId)) {
            UserGroupUser userGrpUser= new UserGroupUser();
            userGrpUser.setName(userGroupDto.getNameLl());
            userGrpUser.setSelected(true);
        userDetials.getUsergroups().add(userGrpUser);
        }
        if (mapSubsidiary.containsKey(user.getCreusrCf())) {
            userDetials.getSubsidaries().addAll(mapSubsidiary.get(user.getCreusrCf()));
            }
        
        userDetials.getProjDetails().addAll(projectService.aggregateProjectDetails(projectService.listProjectsByUserId(null)));
        return userDetials;
        
    }

    @Override
    public AntaresDisplayUser getUserDetails() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
  

I tried by creating the following JUnit test.

 
     @Test
      public void TestUserDetails () {
         
         
         userService.getUserDetails();
         UserServiceImpl userService = new UserServiceImpl();
         String userid1 = "O635";
         String userid2 = "O635";
         assertEquals("O635", "O635");
        
         }
```

Kindly tell me how to perform the JUnit test by storing the values from database for this method.

Comment: What precise problem are you having doing this?

Comment: Please help me write JUnit test case for this method correctly. I am not able to validate data from database and use assertequals correctly in this JUnit test. Please find my below Junit test. @Test public void TestUserDetails () { userService.getUserDetails("O635"); AntaresUserDetials userdetails = userService.getUserDetails("O635"); assertNotNull("O635", userdetails); String expectedUserId = "O635"; assertEquals(expectedUserId, userService.getUserDetails(expectedUserId)); }